# Apply mapping to a list in R

Tags: r

How can I apply a mapping (stored in a list) to a vector?

Consider I have a mapping defined in this way:

```
m <- list(foo='bar', a='b', 1=2)
```

I can get a single list element by just writing something like `m[['foo']]`. What I want to do is to get a list values for multiple keys at once. An obvious solution would be just iterating through the vector:

```
a <- c('foo', 'a')
b <- c()
for (it in a) {b <- c(b, m[[it]])}
```

But looks like this is not an R-style. Can I do it with a one-liner? I also tried using lapply() and mapply() with get() function, but didn't succeed in that.

Please note: I'm new to R, so I may use some terms improperly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m <- list(foo='bar', a='b', c = 'baz')
a <- c("foo", "a")
unlist(m[a])
##  foo     a 
## "bar"   "b"
```